# Insert into MySQL database with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I'm experiencing some kind of a problem here, I have no idea what's wrong with this code. I'm pretty sure it's client sided since I am not getting any PHP errors, but I may be wrong.

I'm trying to get a form, once submitted, to insert the information contained in a text field into a MySQL database via an AJAX request to a PHP file.

Here's where I'm at:

```
/* index.php */

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ajax.js"></script>


//...


        <div class="success" id="success"></div>
        <div class="err" id="err"></div>


 <!--Create Form-->
 <form action="" method="post" name="create" id="createForm" onsubmit="createNew(document.create.create2.value); return false;">        
        <h5>Create New File</h5>
        <p><input name="create2" type="text" maxlength="32" /></p>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create" />
 </form>


/* ajax.js */

function createNew(name)
{
 $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../utilities/process.php",
  data: 'name='+name,
  datatype: "html",
  success: function(msg){

   if(parseInt(msg)!=5)
   {
    $('#success').html('Successfully added ' + name + ' into database.');
    $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
    alert('success');//testing purposes
   }
   else
   {
    $('#err').html('Failed to add ' + name + ' into database.');
    $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
    alert('fail');//testing purposes
   }
  }
      })
}


/* process.php */

<?
include('db_connect.php');

if($_POST['name'])
{
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $name = mysql_escape_string($name);
 $query = "INSERT INTO tz_navbar (name) VALUES (".$name.")";
 $result = mysql_query("$query") or die ("5");

}
?>
```

Here's my problem:
After I submit my form with something, it reports that is succeeds but nothing gets added to my database.

Thank you all in advance for taking your time to help me.

Comment: You can always try $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); to capture the mysql error message.  This will tell you exactly what's going on with any failed query.

Comment: On a security note, make sure you escape the value of $name before storing it in your database.  A malicious user could take advantage of this query as you currently have it written.  For more information, see the Bobby Tables entry on PHP: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: As you can see, calvinf. [$name = mysql_escape_string($name);] This part escapes the strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your query, I suspect you need it to be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tz_navbar (name) VALUES ('".$name."')";
```

If that doesn't fix it, you need to log the value of $_REQUEST

```
error_log(print_r($_REQUEST,true));
```

to ensure that you are getting the right values on the server side.

Comment: I think Paul is right. I suspect that your post value isn't getting passed to your PHP script properly.  Trying using the JSON style to pass your values in your AJAX request. { name: name }

Comment: It seems to be passed perfectly, it was really an attention error from my part on the query.

Answer (score 1):

You have $_POST['name'] , but in your form you have, input type = text name = "create"
Which should be $_POST['create'] . That is why your $_POST['name'] does not have any value when it's passed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your query.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tz_navbar (name) VALUES ('$name');
```

Also, you could try testing process.php without javascript. Just so you could see the mysql error message. Use `die()` or something.

Comment: In fact, I used die(mysql_error()); and I used alert(); with javascript to get my error from process.php