# On click INSERT INTO mySQL without updating the current page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working with PHP and mySQL. On **page1.php** there will be an image that when the user clicks on it there will be a query that inserts into mysql some data. How can I do this without reloading the page or transferring the user someone else and change the image?

What I did so far is to do this but with reloading the page.

Thanks for your ideas/examples.

Comment: jquery, my friend :) You will need to use ajax to make the post asynchrousnously, so the page doesn't refresh...

Comment: funny that you have tagged it as AJAX - have you thought about using AJAX for this task.......?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798001/insert-into-mysql-database-with-jquery-and-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simples as executing the post method of jQuery library.

Here is an example that calls a PHP script when clicking any image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").click(function() {
        $.post("executequery.php");
    });
});
```

In the "executequery.php" you would need to build the SQL and execute it.

Here is the documentation of the method. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks for this, I added `<img src="image.png"></img>` can you please provide me some more code?

Comment: What code you need? You may need to send some parameters to the PHP script, but that's something you need to decide based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, add an ajax call to a php script which should be able to run the insert script and return a success message.